# How to prevent non-deterministic state updation in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When working with Redux, maintaining the shape of the initial state is crucial. The results/data of side effects like API call will change the shape of the state since we have no control over the properties. For example, consider this initial state:

```
const book = {
  id: 0,
  name: 'something'
};
```

And updation is made to it by the book sub-reducer as follows based on the API data:

```
//receives `book` part of the state
const bookReducer = (state=book, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
     case 'SET_BOOK': {
       return { ...action.payload };
     } default: 
       return state;
   }
}
```

Two scenarios that could happen:

1. If the data sent from the API is `null,` then newly produced state is now `{}` as a result of the spread operator. If some parts of UI were to listen to the `book` part of the state, then it will break. Possibly  access individual properties from the API data? In that case, null/undefined checks needs to be performed for properties. Is there a more elegant solution?
2. There could also be additional properties in the data which we may not be interested in. Possibly use an object mapper to filter unused properties?

What is the best practice to handle these kind of scenarios and prevent state becoming non-deterministic? Please share your experience on how you approached these scenarios.

Comment: That is why you usually merge the two existing state with the updates coming in. `return { ...state, ...action.payload };`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli The values of the properties(id and name) coming from the API can be `null` as well. In this case, there is a need to perform null checks and provide default values to the properties to prevent UI from breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Only the reducer has to be pure/deterministic, not the stuff outside of it.

To prevent your reducer from overwriting data incorrectly, write some logic between the API response and the dispatch-call to ensure the reducer always gets valid data.

For example a thunk might look like:

```js
const createBook = (name) => {
  return async dispatch => {
   // suppose the api call gives back "uid" plus extra data
   const { uid, ...unneededData } = await myApi.setBook(name);

   // dispatch the data in the way the reducer expects it 
   dispatch({ type: 'SET_BOOK', id: uid, name });
  }
}
```

In the above example, the api call gives me `uid`, but no `name`, and a bunch of extra data. Just prepare the data before dispatching it.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is the one where you prevent your app from breaking from every aspect, which means you need to check and format your data before returning from the reducer.
In your case, I would check for both data validity and map it to a necessary format.

1. only dispatch 'SET_BOOK' if API response has both id and book.
2. in order to avoid unnecessary additional properties, you can always map your data `const book = {id: apiData.id, book: apiData.book}` before dispatching.

Answer (score 0):

In your reducer you can do like below. This way only `id` and `name` will get updated even though there are other key/values in the response. Also this will make sure that if null values are received then those values will not be updated in the state. Hope this will help in resolving the issue.

```js
    //receives `book` part of the state
    const bookReducer = (state=book, action) => {
      const { type, payload } = action;
       switch(type) {
         case 'SET_BOOK': {
           return { 
             ...state,
             ...(payload.id && {id: payload.id}),
             ...(payload.name && {name: payload.name})
           };
         } default: 
           return state;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your redux reducer logic should not worry about that due to its deterministic nature. You handle your api call and response handling elsewhere (redux thunk or component), and then dispatch the action to set your redux. Building off of your example:

book.reducer.js

```
const book = {
  id: 0,
  name: ''
};

const bookReducer = (state=book, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
     case 'SET_BOOK': {
       return { ...action.payload };
     } default: 
       return state;
   }
```

book.actions.js

```
const setBook = (book) => ({
    type: SET_HEROES,
    payload: book
});

// thunk
const findBook = name => async dispatch => {
    const book = await bookService.findBook(name);

    if (book) {
        dispatch(setBook(book));
    }
};
```

book.service.js

```
const findBook = async (name) => {
    // Do your api call
    const bookResponse = axios.get(`${apiUrl}/book/search/${name}`);

    // Handle the response
    if (!bookResponse) {
      // Logic you do if book not found
      return null;
    }

    return {id: bookResponse.id, name: bookResponse.name};
}
```

Now in a component you can just dispatch the findBook call

Component.js

```
    const Component = () => {
        const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
        const dispatch = useDispatch();

        const handleOnSearch = () => {
            dispatch(findBook(search));
        }

        return (
             <div>
                 <input value={search} onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>
                 <button onClick={handleOnSearch}>Search</button>
             </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If field value from API is undefined then convert it into null and store so that the code doesn't break and operatable. If API gives other params as well then de-structure the API returned object and extract the required fields. So that storing unnecessary data can be avoided.

```
const bookReducer = (state=book, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
     case 'SET_BOOK': {
        const {id, name, otherParam1, otherParam2} = action.payload;
        return {
          id: id || null,
          name: name || null,
          otherParam1,
          otherParam2
        }
     } default: 
       return state;
   }
}
```

> Having the value `null` won't break the code instead, it renders nothing
>   which is better than `undefined` which breaks the code

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to have all of my logic in my action method and create reducers for when an action is correctly fulfilled and another one for when is rejected. In the fulfilled reducer, I would do the regular instructions and in the rejected reducer I would add the data to a variable called error which I always have in my state and use in the frontend to show an error message if needed.

Example

This is an action that creates a house by sending a post request to my api which returns the created object or an error if something went wrong.

```
export const createHouse = houseData => {
  const URL = HTTP://EXAMPLE.URL

  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${URL}`, houseData);
      const data = await response.data;
      dispatch({ type: "CREATE_HOUSE_DRAFT_FULFILLED", data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "CREATE_HOUSE_DRAFT_REJECTED", data: err });
    }
  };
};
```

Then I would have 2 reducer methos to recieve the fulfilled or the rejected response, like this.

```
        case 'CREATE_HOUSE_DRAFT_FULFILLED': {
            return {
                houses: [action.data, ...state.houses],
                house: action.data,
                houseCount: state.houseCount + 1,
                fetched: true,
                error: null
            };
        }
        case 'CREATE_HOUSE_DRAFT_REJECTED': {
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.data.response.data,
                fetched: false,
                success: null
            };
        }
```

Hope this works for you!